# Why am I getting this error on MessageBox?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, messagebox

All I want is to pop-up a simple messagebox to display a warning that a required field is empty, but I am getting this error:

> Argument not specified for parameter 'p1' of 'Private Property
>   MessageBox(p1 As String) As System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox'.

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    'validation
    If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNameSurname.Text) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Name can not be empty", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'if valid calc Membership No
    txtMemberNo.Text = setMembershipNo(dateBirth.Value.Date)

    'call Athlete class to add data

End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like you have a property called `MessageBox`. Why would you do that?! Show us the code where you declare that property, and tell us what are you using it for because you probably don't want it to be of type `MessageBox` either.

Comment: I am not I am just trying to use the standard messagebox build into VB to display a pop-up message to a user.

Comment: A message box is a prefabricated modal dialog box for displaying information to users. A message box is opened by calling the static Show method of the MessageBox class. When Show is called, the message is passed using a string parameter. Several overloads of Show allow you to configure how a message box will appear

Comment: I know you are. But you still have a property somewhere in your class (or in a module) called `MessageBox`. Look for it and once you find it, edit your question and include the new information I referred to in my previous comment.

Comment: I didn't ask you to copy the definition of the MessageBox from [MS-Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/how-to-open-a-message-box), I know what a MessageBox is.

Comment: My appologies you are correct I have found  a declaration :( Private Property MessageBox(ByVal p1 As String) As MessageBox. Thanks it is working!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171157/discussion-between-aquaalex-and-ahmed-abdelhameed).

Comment: @AquaAlex - If you have an answer then please post as an answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity I did

Comment: @AquaAlex - Sorry, I meant don't append it to your question - I edited it out.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ahmed-abdelhameed 
I had a function defined with a name of messagebox, once I renamed the function and everything worked.

Comment: Actually, "renamed it" is only part of the solution. What are you using it for? You can't create an instance of the `MessageBox` class anyway! What exactly does it return? This is why I asked you to edit your question, include the implementation of it, and explain what you need it for if you want further help.

Comment: i was not creating an instance, i copied some standard code from another project and in there was a function called message box which does not make sense, so i just renamed the function and everything worked. (I was not even using the function so deleted it)